# MVC "Branding Image" by Request String?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC app, I have images in the following place. This is from the _Layout.cshtml:

```
<a href="#"><img src="~/Content/app/images/logo-tlc.png" alt="TLC"></a>
```

I am tring to change the "brand image" by parsing the query string, say pass "apl" for Animal Planet. I have attempted the following without knowing if you can even do this kind of concating strings. It does not work:

```
<a href="#"><img src="~/Content/app/images/logo-" + @Request["brand"] + ".png" alt=@Request["brand"]>
```

How can I accomplish this?

It's now rendering:

```
<
               <img src="/Content/app/images/logo-" + apl + ".png" alt=apl>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer... and you do not need to wrap your values in quotes in the querystring.

Comment: yes, I saw what the issue is, I've updated my answer...

Comment: For all of these answers make sure you only access a querystring directly inside your page markup in a server with Request Filtering. Without request filtering a technique like these shown open your site up for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be referencing the `QueryString[]` collection?  Also use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() to unescape your querystring.

```
<img src="~/Content/app/images/logo-@(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["brand"])).png" alt=@(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString["brand"]))>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me if I use a query string like http://localhost:55335/Home/Login?brand=%22apl%22

Comment: you need to escape the chars, use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`

Comment: and what are those escaped chars?  quotes?  why do you need them?  they don't seem necessary

Comment: querystring values do not need quotes they should `key=value&` with an ampersand separating other parameters.  Your examples are `key="value"` and that is excessive and unnecessary.

Comment: I;m sorry, I still can''t get it to work by using http://localhost:55335/?brand=apl

Comment: do a view source and update your question with what it is rendering

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer again, you had too many `"` and you were concatenating the string...

Comment: It works now. I've marked it as the answer but what if they don't type in a query string?

Comment: you should handle that in your controller, add a property to a model to hold the image url info.  You can default the value in the controller.

Comment: How? There is no controller running yet. This code is in the Master View so it shows the image for all views. Its in _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

A better answer would be to collect the brand request parameter in your controller action, and store it in session or build a special viewmodel that knows brand and points to the correct url.  Any example shown where the image url is built in the view from a request parameter is either going to be open to XSS or null pointer when the parameter isn't passed.

```
public ActionResult Index( string brand ) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(brand)) {
        brand = "TLC"; 
    }
    Session["brand"] = brand;
    return View();
}
```

And then in your view:

```
<img src="@string.format("~/Content/app/images/logo-{0}.png", Session["brand"])" alt="@Session["brand"]">`
```

Comment: The trouble is that I am not doing this in a view but the master view _Layout.cshtml

Comment: I've solved that situation before by creating a OnActionExecuting filter inside of a base controller that all of my controllers then extend.  That way, it gets run for all actions, and get changed if need be.

Comment: I see no value added by moving the parameter to session, you are just changing `Request.QueryString` for `Session`.  I would agree that adding a model property to hold this value is better but there is no real *functional* difference between session and querystring for this scenario.  Also you should avoid using `Session` for trivial items like this.

Comment: Adding the null check around the parameter allows for the view to not crash if the parameter doesn't exist.  Also, having a View access the request object feels icky to me and sorta feels like it violates the idea of MVC.  That sorta feels like a controller thing.

Comment: It may feel icky but my comment using Session etc.. is not a good standard to hold.  You could easily create some `static` Helper classes to handle null checks, defaults..

Comment: It may be a trivial usage of session, but then they'd have the brand available everywhere in his application, and not have to pass it page to page.  if they're setting it on _layout.cshtml, they obviously want it to appear more than once, or else they'd just put it on the page they need it on.

Comment: seems unnecessary, there are other request wide mechanisms that could be used but to each their own.